# model.toJSON() returns empty object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been playing around with Backbone.js and ran into something a bit unexpected. It seems that toJSON() (and as a result of attributes) will only return a JSON object if I explicitly set the attributes. Here's the issue:

1. Extend/inherit a sample object with some data
2. grab the resulting constructor
3. instantiate/new an instance
4. call the `toJSON()` function

I expected the call to return my object with all attributes (inherited and bound), but instead I got back an empty `{}` object.

Here's the sample code:

```
var TestModelConstructor = Backbone.Model.extend({ name: "test", num: 483 });
var testinstance = new TestModelConstructor;

console.log(testinstance.name); //prints: test
console.log(testinstance.num);  //prints: 483
console.log(JSON.stringify(testinstance.toJSON())); //prints: {}
console.log(testinstance.attributes); //again empty object

testinstance.newattr = "adding new attribute";
console.log(testinstance.attributes); //{}  ????

//either set explicitly by calling "set" or via constructor/initialize
testinstance.set({ label: "i can setz attributez" });
console.log(JSON.stringify(testinstance.toJSON())); 
                                      //{"label":"i can setz attributez"}
console.log(testinstance.attributes); //{"label":"i can setz attributez"}
```

Either this behavior is strange or I missed something in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be using the `defaults` parameter to the `extend` function to set the defaults.  Parameters passed to the extend function will be members on the class rather than attributes, which is what `toJSON` uses.

```
var TestModelConstructor = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : { name: "test", num: 483 }
});
var testinstance = new TestModelConstructor;
....
```

See the [defaults documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-defaults) for more details.

To be clear, the attributes `Backbone.Model` uses are stored in the `attributes` member of the class rather than on the actual class itself.  This avoids confusing actual model data with functions that you call on the model and settings that you use to configure the model.  It's these functions and settings that you're creating/setting when you pass arguments to the `Model.extend` function.

So when you're trying to set `testinstance.newattr` you should actually use `testinstance.attributes.newattr` instead.  This is what the `.set` method is actually doing behind the scenes, so I'd recommend just using `.set`.

Again, the [attributes documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-attributes) has more details

Comment: Thanks. Going over the attributes section again does clarify the question. I wish the documentation was more clear in terms of outlining the conventions used in this MVC framework. When I first read it, I had taken that as a recommendation rather than the convention.

Comment: No problem.  I actually ran into a similar bit of confusion myself a while back - I've found most of the information you need is in the documentation it just takes some proper reading to get it out.  Anyway, if you think this is the correct answer please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

in fact you mixed it up

where you did:

```
var TestModelConstructor = Backbone.Model.extend({ name: "test", num: 483 });
```

you should have done:

```
var TestModelConstructor = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

**remark** keep in mind the has does not need to be empty, but just for testing extending a new model without any custom methods is enough.

then, when you did:

```
var testinstance = new TestModelConstructor;
```

you should have done:

```
var testinstance = new TestModelConstructor({ name: "test", num: 483 });
```

**remark** here, you create a new object of that defined Model, and you give your modelObject some values, a name and a num.

these attributes are only available in the instance though, they are properties of the instance.
if you want those properties as defaults on every instance you should set them in the model definitions when you extend from `Backbone.Model`. like this:

```
var TestModelConstructor = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'defaultname',
        num: 0
    }
});
```

**remark** every instance you now create will get `'defaultname'` as a name property (unless you create your instance with given values for the name property.

to sum it up:

```
var TestModelConstructor = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'defaultname',
        num: 0
    }
});

// create a test instance
var testinstance = new TestModelConstructor();

console.log(testinstance.get('name'));  // output:   defaultname

// create a testinstance and override the defaults (you can override them partially)
var testinstance2 = new TestModelConstructor({ name: "test", num: 483 });

console.log(testinstance.get('name'));  // output:   test
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this excellent remark. I completely missed the prototypal inheritance aspect of using defaults vs explicitly setting constructors for instance values. When I was trying my initial version (in the question), I saw the attributes on my model's prototype and not on the model itself, but I didn't pay much attention to it at the time. But this certainly helps put things in perspective.